# Appending a trailing slash if needed

Tags: java, url

I like to overcomplicate things, this is fairly simple though but I would like to keep it simpler without lowering readability. Not just to improve my code but also my self.

```
private String checkTrailingSlash(String website) {
    if(!website.endsWith("/")){
        website = website + "/";
    }
    return website;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

You could use a ternary operator to inline the condition into a single `return` statement:

```
private String checkTrailingSlash(String website) {
    return website.endsWith("/") ? website : website + "/";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, I'm not sure how much simpler you can make this.

I'd suggest a slightly clearer name though - maybe `ensureTrailingSlash`? `checkX` sounds more like a predicate. My other suggestion would be to add some spaces in your if-conditional, depending on your taste:

```
if (!website.endsWith("/")) {
```

This could be a static method, as well.

Answer (score 9):

It would be less verbose to write

```
website += "/";
```

instead of

> ```
> website = website + "/";
> ```

So, yeah, you totally overcomplicated it.  =)

Also, instead of `checkTrailingSlash`, it would be clearer if renamed to `ensureTrailingSlashExists`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like `if` statements in your code, then you could use something like this:

```
website=website.replaceAll("([^/])$","$1/") ;
```

it uses a regex to replace last character only if it is NOT a `/` with the last character plus the `/`.

Comment: "I would like to keep it simpler without lowering readability"
I would argue that a regex approach rarely doesn't lower readability

Comment: Yes but it has the big advantage not to be pipeable

Comment: Alternatively you could use lookbehind: `website.replaceFirst("(?<!/)$","/")`. This avoids having to use a backreference. Using the regex `"/?$"` looks even simpler, but has the disadvantage that it allocates a new string even when the original has a trailing slash already.

Answer (score 1):

Since often browsers also support backslashes, you can also consider this:

```
public static String addTrailingSlashIfMissing(String str) {
    String slashChar = str.contains("\\") ? "\\" : "/";
    return str.endsWith(slashChar) ? str : str + slashChar;
}
```

which can be also useful for file system paths.